# Busca com Inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, firebase, firebird

Estou fazendo uma busca onde o usuario entra com o ID do pedido e o sistema faz devolve a observaçaõ do pedido, codigo dos produtos e qtd. E esses dados estao dispostos em 2 tabelas. (Nao criei o banco, ele ja veio  pronto) Porem, com a minha consulta usando innerjoin o console diz que a pesquisa está ambigua.
tb_ped_venda é onde está a quantidade e o id dos produtos
tb_pedido_venda é onde está obervações do pedido.

```
SELECT TB_PED_VENDA_ITEM.ID_IDENTIFICADOR,
TB_PED_VENDA_ITEM.QTD_ITEM,TB_PEDIDO_VENDA.OBSERVACAO 
FROM TB_PED_VENDA_ITEM INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDO_VENDA
ON TB_PED_VENDA_ITEM.ID_PEDIDO = TB_PEDIDO_VENDA.ID_PEDIDO
WHERE ID_PEDIDO=$id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O banco retorna a mensagem ambigua quando você tem um campo está em mais de uma tabela do select, neste seu caso provavelmente é o ID_PEDIDO da clausula where.

Tente colocar o nome da tabela na frente:

```
where B_PED_VENDA_ITEM.ID_PEDIDO=$id
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema, mas nao está exibindo a o campo observaçaõ da tabela pedido_venda

Comment: Desculpe, o erro era no meu banco. o campo OBS está como um tipo q n conheço. BLOB. tentei outro campo e deu, desculpe. E obrigado!

Comment: Disponha, estamos aí para ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

Faltou especificar a tabela.

```
WHERE TB_PED_VENDA_ITEM.ID_PEDIDO=$id"
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Como `ID_PEDIDO` é uma coluna presente em mais de uma delas, o *planner* precisa saber a qual se refere.

O fato de ambos serem iguais no seu caso específico é "mera coincidência". (Ok, na verdade daria para deduzir programaticamente, mas não faz sentido adicionar esta complexidade no *query planner* só para que o programador não faça a parte dele).

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver, haha